# Is outer derived class visible through C#.NET reflection of inner class inherited from parent?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, reflection, inner-classes

In the following code example I want to inherit class B from class A and be able to get name of class B if I have only object of type B.AC.

So my subject question can be specified as: **Is class B visible through C#.NET reflection of B.AC ?**

Based on accepted answer - the answer is "no", I have to declare `new class AC` inside B and derive it from A.AC.

```
using System;
namespace Question{
    class Program{
        class A{
           public class AC{}
        }
        class B: A{
           //new public class AC:A.AC{} // work around to get B+AC
        }
        class D: A{
           new public class AC:A.AC{} // work around to get D+AC
           public class DAC:A.AC{} // just another example
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var b_ac = new B.AC{}.GetType();
            var B_AC = typeof(B.AC);
            var D_AC = typeof(D.AC);
            var DAC = typeof(D.DAC);
            Func<Type,string> enclosure = (x)=>{
                Console.WriteLine(x.DeclaringType.Name);  // gives A - wrong
                Console.WriteLine(x.BaseType.Name);  // gives Object - wrong
                Console.WriteLine(x.FullName);  // gives A+AC - wrong, I want B+AC
                Console.WriteLine(x.ReflectedType.FullName);  // gives A - wrong
                return "B"; // I want to get name of class B through reflection
            };

           Console.WriteLine(enclosure(b_ac)); // gives A+AC - wrong, see details above
           Console.WriteLine(enclosure(B_AC)); // gives same wrong
           Console.WriteLine(enclosure(D_AC)); // gives D+AC - good
           Console.WriteLine(enclosure(DAC)); // gives D+DAC - good
           Console.ReadKey();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure what the question is but, `B.AC` and `A.AC` refer to the same type. In C#, `B.AC` is merely another legal name that can be used to refer to `A.AC`. It is similar to how `ReferenceEquals` is a static method on `System.Object`, but `A.ReferenceEquals` is another way to access the same method. However, the compiler converts these names to the proper ones in IL so you will never see B.AC or A.ReferenceEquals via reflection.

Comment: `BaseType` for both nested classes **are** object since they are only *declared* in, not *based on* their owning types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to redefine AC using `new` to do this. If you look at the reflected code using something like ILSpy you will see that it is actually constructing the line `var b_ac = new B.AC{}.GetType();` as `newobj instance void Question.Program/A/AC::.ctor()`. It is invoking the constructor defined in `A` as though you had done `new A.AC{}.GetType()`.

Comment: Accurate answer to my subject question is "no", see my clarified specific question, but this answer is understandable anyway.